# java Spring import error

Tags: java, spring

I've downloaded spring-framework-4.1.6.RELEASE from http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/

Then I followed the Spring Website http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ to start a project,but I found there is a problem in it.

```
//The import org.springframework.boot cannot be resolved
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

It seems like that it can't find the jar files so can't import it,but I've add all jar files to build path.
How can I solve it? Is Spring and SpringFramework the same one?

Comment: Have you added the JAR as a dependency in your IDE ? What IDE are you using ?

Comment: I've added all.I use eclipse.

Comment: Don't hunt for jars manually use something like maven or gradle to do that for you. It will save you a lot of time and headaches... When following those guides there are always 2 flavors a Maven and Gradle one. Pick either one but please don't hunt for jars yourself in these days anymore...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access classes which are part of the Spring Boot project, it might be the case that your Spring libraries do not contain the Spring Boot project related libraries.

Naturally I'd recommend for you to import it via Maven or Gradle as suggested by the [Spring Boot Quickstart.](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start)

But if you want to add it manually, the latest release jar currently for `SpringApplication` is spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar

Find it [HERE](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.2.3.RELEASE)

And the `SpringBootApplication` class is found within spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar

Find it [HERE](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.3.RELEASE)

So check if you have similar jars among your current ones and download them if not, also remember since you are dealing with dependencies manually, it's quite possible that these two new libraries will have dependencies of their own and you'll have to accommodate to them as well.

Comment: hi. I have downloaded with maven in STS still i am not able to add @SpringBootApplication on the class. please help me.

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
 
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>. This is my pom.xml

Answer (score 5):

I had the problem that just anything in package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.* could not be resolved/compiled though proper jar was included in classpath.

My solution: wipe the local maven repository

Running command line 'mvn clean compile' showed me a line like

```
[ERROR] error reading /Users/greyshine/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

That gave me the guess that the artefact was not properly downloaded in the first run.
I wiped my maven spring boot repository artefacts (i.e located at ~/Users/MYHOME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot) then I rebuild with 'mvn clean compile' and it all worked.

Comment: I wiped the entire directory at this position(C:\Users\user-name\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot) and then updated the maven project (via Maven -> Update Project). It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Spring framework zip` artifact you downloaded off the maven repo doesnt have the `Spring boot` jar, thats why its not compiling.
Download the spring boot jar and add it to your classpath.

This link has the maven dependency defined.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by tweaking the pom.xml

from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to Dirk Schumacher's approach of removing the entire local maven repo, I only remove the .m2/repository/org/springframework folder to force that part to redownload.